# How to get the default value of an object after creating new?

Tags: php, object, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to laravel and php and I need some help.

**Model**/Object

```
<?php

class Alert {

    public function type()
    {
        return 'default';
    }
    public function title()
    {
        return '';
    }
    public function message()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
 @if (isset($alert))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ $alert->type }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <strong>{{ $alert->title }}</strong> {{ $alert->message }}
    </div>
    @endif
```

**My Usage** - This works well.

```
    $alert = new Alert;
    $alert->type = 'success';
    $alert->title = '';
    $alert->message = 'Successfully Added';
```

**My Usage w/ Error** - This gives me an error because I removed the `$alert->title`.

```
    $alert = new Alert;
    $alert->type = 'success';
    $alert->message = 'Successfully Added';
```

[image: Error]

What I want is when I only specify the `$alert->message` it will still display the message without giving me error and just get the default value from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `public $title = '';` in your class.